# Carousel slide to move behind transparent div instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm completely new to jquery so please bear with me.

I've managed to make the following carousel plugin to work, but I have one minor issue. Whenever I click between slides, the preceding slide or the slide that would "come next" to the slide in either direction, flies across the back of the current slide.

This would not be an issue if the image is completely opaque, but I'm working with transparent backgrounds, so you can really notice the flying across the back.

My question - Is there anyway to disable the "flying across" of slides that are not displayed? or maybe to have the slide move across more discreetly?

Any help would truly be much appreciated...

Thanks very much!

PS: All credit for this carousel to the Filament Group :)

http://jsfiddle.net/HCHS8/

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto;">
<center>
    <div class="carousel arrows" data-transition="slide" style="height: 300px;">
        <div>TEST SLIDE 1 Text here, but if you click to move to next slide, other slide wipes behind (if clear background)</div>
        <div>TESTING SLIDE 2</div>
</center>
```

Comment: I think it would be better/easier for you to raise the issue at their github. That way you can get the creator to answer your question because I don't think that people here are going to dig through several hundred lines of code.

Comment: you can just fadeOut the 'flying' image as soon as the new one is in place, then when animation is over fadeIn again

Comment: Also, your problem lies in the fact that looping divs (the ones in the background) are doing a css transition. Ideally it would be great to put the transition to none temporarily until the looping element moves all the way.

Comment: @MaximErshov I hate to be a pain, but would you mind helping me isolate where in the js code this would be? If it's too much of a pain, don't worry about it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the code, you can just fix the problem with simple CSS. Check this fiddle. I updated some CSS rules for your classes that are used for non active items. looks like now it's working the way you want. http://jsfiddle.net/HCHS8/1/

```
.carousel-item-prev, .carouse-item-next {
    opacity:0;
}
```